# Remove class from parent <td> of unselected radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I would like to do is be able to highlight the parent  of the selected radio button, which I have done. The thing I am having trouble with is removing the .sel class from the unselected radios. I will have multiple radio groups set up in a table, one group for each row.

Here is my code up to now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('td.radio').click(function () {
    $(this).children('input').prop('checked', true);

    if ($(this).children('input').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).addClass('sel');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('sel');
    }
});
});
```

I have a jsFiddle set up here with what I have managed so far: http://jsfiddle.net/ASMITH/drYTP/5/

Comment: sorry should have made it clearer, the ability to select the radio by clicking its parent <td> (as above) is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the sel class from all siblings of the td that was clicked, then add it to the one that was clicked:

```
    $('td.radio').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.children('input').prop('checked', true);       
        $this.siblings('td').removeClass('sel');        
        $this.addClass('sel');        
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/drYTP/6/

Comment: this looks spot on, got close to this at one point though I've not come across the .siblings selector before. Thanks mate!

Comment: No problem. The documentation is very helpful and easy to use. This sort of thing is under traversing: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('td.radio').removeClass('sel').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('input:checked').length;
}).addClass('sel');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/drYTP/17/) (Note that two `radio` elements are `checked` by default on page-load).

For a more dynamic approach (I had, originally, assumed it was an on page-load event, for some reason) use:

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('td').addClass('sel').siblings().removeClass('sel');
})
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/drYTP/19/)

Comment: the fiddle does not seem to do anything, does not remove red and does not add red

Answer (score 0):

Tested this on jsfiddle.  It removes the highlight only from the row that was clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('td.radio').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().children().each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        $(this).removeClass('sel');
    });
    $(this).children('input').prop('checked', true);
    $(this).addClass('sel');

});
});
```

edit --

not sure it was what you were looking for, but with the multiple rows, it seemed like that was what you were after.  http://jsfiddle.net/ASMITH/drYTP/5/

edit 2 --

fixed some formatting

Answer (score 0):

I would do things slightly differently to make the code more logical.

But first, here's a fiddle demo (thanks for supplying one!): http://jsfiddle.net/MU2Se/

Here's an explanation:

Instead of checking for clicks on the `<td>` elements (labeled as .radio), check for a click on the actual form element.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    // ...
}
```

Because radio buttons get grouped by the element name, get the element name of the radio that was clicked so you can target that group.

```
var name = $(this).attr('name');
```

With the radio group handy, simply loop through each element and remove the class.

```
$('input[name="'+name+'"]').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('sel');
});
```

*Note*: I like this approach a little more as it doesn't force you to unset/reset all items, only the ones in the group.  It helps save a little extra checks on items we don't need to deal with.

Since we changed the code to trigger on the click of the given radio, we can simply add the class back to the button that was clicked.

```
 $(this).parent().addClass('sel');
```

I hope that helps!